# load xml containing non-ascii characters in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to parse xml in python 2.7 with following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys, json

txtfile='game_file.txt'

def jd(payload):
    return json.dumps(payload, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def parse_demo_txt(demofile):
    tree = ET.ElementTree(file=demofile)
    scores={}
    for player in tree.iter('player'):
        if player.attrib['name'] not in scores:
            scores[player.attrib['name']]={'death':player.attrib['deaths'], 'win': player.attrib['spree'], 'totalscore': player.attrib['frags']}

    return scores

parse_demo_txt(txtfile)
```

Source file contains some non-ascii characters which are generating error

```
$ python parse_xml.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_xml.py", line 38, in <module>
    parse_demo_xml(xmlfile)
  File "parse_xml.py", line 18, in parse_demo_xml
    tree = ET.ElementTree(file=xmlfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 611, in __init__
    self.parse(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 656, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1653, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1517, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 5, column 14
```

Indeed, in line 5, column 14 there are some non-ascii characters. Is there a way around it (using pure element tree) other that parsing this file first and converting these problematic characters?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Without it, your code is considered off-topic here. Also make sure you do some research on the errors you get before asking redundant questions.

Comment: Thanks. Above code is working just fine. Only missing part is that *game_file.txt* but I don't know how to attach it here to keep original encoding. I could post it somewhere but links may not be seen as something positive here. Also, I sorted out my problem writting separate function which I'm about to share in a minute.

Comment: Glad you found a solution, but that's not the point. Writing sloppy, incomplete questions that are then guessed rather than analyzed and answered isn't helpful to a site dedicated to providing a knowledgebase of questions and answers. That's the reason your question must contain a MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is not an encoding error but a XML one. XML do support non ascii characters (hopefully !) so the issue is not with having non-ascii characters but with having non-ascii characters in a document declaring an ASCII encoding (in the `<?XML ...?>` line).

If you know the real encoding for this document, just fix the `encoding` declaration. Else, well, send back this XML file to whoever created it and ask him for a valid XML file... At worse you can try using `chardet` or `UnicodeDammit` to try and guess the encoding but remember that it will still be a wild guess.

Comment: There is no encoding in the header at all. Adding encoding="UTF-8" did not change a thing.

Comment: Adding "encoding=UTF-8" is only useful if it's UTF-8, and without the xml file anything more is just a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

OK I ended up writting my own function to remove unwanted characters from original file and then passing it to XML parser.

```
def normalize_player(demofile):
    ''' this function will normalize player="" field in xml file by removind non-ascii characters from it 
        and writting output to name_normalized file.
    '''
    with open(demofile+'_normalized', 'w') as normalized_file:
        with open(demofile, 'r') as inputfile:
            for line in inputfile:
                if '<player' in line and 'name' in line:
                    plname=re.findall('name="(.*)" team', line)
                    # print('line stripped: {}'.format(line.rstrip('\r\n')))
                    # print('plname: {}'.format(plname))
                    nname=normalize_nickname(''.join(plname))
                    # print('plname normalized: {}'.format(nname))
                    line=line.replace(''.join(plname),nname)
                    # print('replaced line: {}'.format(line))
                normalized_file.write(line)
    remove(demofile)
    move(demofile+'_normalized', demofile)
```

Function called normalize_nickname() will just replace non-printable ascii characters with normal ones.

```
def normalize_nickname(nickname):
    ''' this function will normalize nickname by making it readable '''
    transformation_table=generate_translation_table()
    normalized_nickname=[]
    for character in nickname:
        normalized_nickname.append(chr(transformation_table[ord(character)]))
    return ''.join(normalized_nickname)
```

Finally, generate_translation_table() function looks like this

```
def generate_translation_table():
    ''' python implementation of https://github.com/deurk/mvdsv/blob/master/src/common.c#L1717 '''
    ascii_table={}

    # some basic transformations
    for i in range (0, 32):
        ascii_table[i] = 35         # '#'
        ascii_table[i + 128] = 35   # '#'
    for i in range (32, 128):
        ascii_table[i] = i
        ascii_table[i + 128] = i

    # special cases
    ascii_table[10] = 10
    ascii_table[13] = 13

    # dot
    ascii_table[5] = 46             # '.'
    ascii_table[14] = 46            # '.'
    ascii_table[15] = 46            # '.'
    ascii_table[28] = 46            # '.'
    ascii_table[46] = 46            # '.'
    ascii_table[5 + 128] = 46       # '.'
    ascii_table[14 + 128] = 46      # '.'
    ascii_table[15 + 128] = 46      # '.'
    ascii_table[28 + 128] = 46      # '.'
    ascii_table[46 + 128] = 46      # '.'

    # numbers
    for i in range (18, 28):
        ascii_table[i] = i + 30
        ascii_table[i + 128] = i + 30

    # brackets
    ascii_table[16] = 91            # '['
    ascii_table[16 + 128] = 91      # '['
    ascii_table[17] = 93            # ']'
    ascii_table[17 + 128] = 93      # ']'
    ascii_table[29] = 40            # '('
    ascii_table[29 + 128] = 40      # '('
    ascii_table[128] = 40           # '('
    ascii_table[31] = 41            # ')'
    ascii_table[31 + 128] = 41      # ')'
    ascii_table[130] = 41           # ')'

    # left arrow
    ascii_table[127] = 62           # '>'

    # right arrow
    ascii_table[141] = 60           # '<'

    # =
    ascii_table[30] = 61            # '='
    ascii_table[30+128] = 61        # '='
    ascii_table[129] = 61           # '='

    return ascii_table
```